# redirect to another controller method directly avoiding the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying C# MVC and I have stumbled on the following issue. I am playing with a small project which is sort of task management tool. At this moment I have 2 (user, task) models and corresponding controllers and set of views.
The user controler has an method 'Create' which obviously create a new user basing on the data received from the form. When the user is created a task should be automatically created for him. Here is my user controller create/register method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "userId,dateCreated,dateRemoved,level,firstName,lastName,login,emailAddress,password")] User user)
    {
        user.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.User.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Tasks", new { Id = user.userId });


           //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

Here is the Create Task method of the task controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "taskId,dateCreated,dateAssigned,userId,assigneeId,taskCategory,taskType,taskPriority,taskStatus,taskName,dateDue,dateClosed,Comments")] Task task, int? Id)
    {
        task.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;

        if (Id != null)
        {
            task.userId = (int)Id;
            task.dateAssigned = DateTime.Now;
            task.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            task.dateDue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            task.taskCategory = taskCategory.assigned;
            task.taskType = taskType.System_Induction;
            task.assigneeId = 2;
            task.taskPriority = taskPriority.Low;
            task.taskName = "Iduction to TaskManagementTool";
            task.Comments = "Please go through the following training materials:";
            task.taskStatus = taskStatus.Assigneed;



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Tasks.Add(task);


                db.SaveChanges();

                ViewBag.TaskAssignedNotification = "Hello " + Session["login"].ToString() + " you have new task assigned" ;


                switch (Session["level"].ToString())
                { 
                    case "Basic":
                        return RedirectToAction("LoggedAsBasic", "Home");
                        break;

                    default:
                        return RedirectToAction("LoggedAsBasic", "Home");
                }

                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            task.userId = Int32.Parse(Session["userId"].ToString());
            task.taskStatus = taskStatus.Created;


            if (Session["level"].ToString() == "Assigner" && task.taskCategory == taskCategory.assigned)
            {
                task.dateAssigned = DateTime.Now;


            }





            if (Session["level"].ToString() == "Basic")
                task.taskCategory = taskCategory.own;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Tasks.Add(task);


                db.SaveChanges();


                return RedirectToAction("TasksIndex");
            }
        }
        return View(task);
    }
```

While creating the new user the new user Id should be passed to Create method of the task controller and predefined task (in if (Id != null))should be created for the new user without opening the Create view with the HTML form. Unfortunatley I am not able to call the Create method of the task controller from the user controller. At best I end up with the task create for to be filled. Can you folks help me out on this?

Comment: Sorry, both "create" and "register" method og the user controller point at the "create" method of the task controller

Comment: It seems that your /task/create method is not intended to be used anywhere else, and it's tied in to the user at the point of creating the user. You could remove the /task/create [HttpGet] method and just pass in your userid to the [HttpPost]. You won't need to do the binding or check that the form is valid, since a form is not being filled out and passed in and all you're doing is initializing.

Comment: Your `Create()` method in `TaskController` needs a parameter for the ID - `public ActionResult Create(int ID)`, and then you need to initialize a new instance of your model, set its `UserID` and pass the model to the view

Comment: @nocturns2 The task/create method is to be used when the new user is created (using the Id passed from user/create method) and when Id is not passed (menainig the existing user creates new task for himself)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the method has the Id parameter:                             public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "taskId,dateCreated,dateAssigned,userId,assigneeId,taskCategory,taskType,taskPriority,taskStatus,taskName,dateDue,dateClosed,Comments")] Task task, int? Id)

Comment: The GET method! - your passing a value (`new { Id = user.userId }`) in the redirect but you never even use it. The value of `userId` in the POST method will always be `0` assuming its typeof `int` because you never set it

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the answer. After db.SaveChanges(); in user/create method the user.userId is 27. After changing task/CreateInitial to GET I have the  CreateInitial view displayed which has no form. All the values are for the new task are set in the task/CreateInitial method. How can I avoid the view and go straight to the method execution?

Comment: You do not have a `CreateInitial()` method in `TaskController` (its named `Create()`).And what do you mean by _I avoid the view and go straight to the method execution_? Its difficult to understand what you trying to so.

Comment: All I needed was to create a new task object in users/create method with the set values so the new task is created right after the new user is created. Thanks for trying to help and sorry for the not very clear description of the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed in this case was new task object created withing the users/create action method togather with the user object so I do not need to point at any other controller/actionresult to create the task.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "userId,dateCreated,dateRemoved,level,firstName,lastName,login,emailAddress,password")] User user, Task task)
    {
        user.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.User.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            task.userId = 2;
            task.dateAssigned = DateTime.Now;
            task.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            task.dateDue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            task.taskCategory = taskCategory.assigned;
            task.taskType = taskType.System_Induction;
            task.assigneeId = user.userId;
            task.taskPriority = taskPriority.Low;
            task.taskName = "Iduction to TaskManagementTool";
            task.Comments = "Please go through the following training materials:";
            task.taskStatus = taskStatus.Assigneed;

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {


                db.Tasks.Add(task);
                db.SaveChanges();



            }


           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```